# Argo Workflow: create a conditional cyclic DAG

Tags: argo-workflows

I want to create a conditional cyclic DAG in Argo Workflow.

My use case: I have a final human-approval step, if rejected, I want to workflow go back to some specific node and rerun from there.

Why rerun makes sense in my case: there're some human inputs in the workflow, if the final result is rejected, they might want to change some parameters and rerun.

Why not rerun the whole workflow: some steps are expensive.

I know cycle is not even a valid word when we're talking about DAG. But I haven't come up with a proper way to handle my usecase in Argo Workflow. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any chance of memoizing the expensive steps?

Comment: @MichaelCrenshaw memorizing sounds like a good idea! I'll try to exploit Argo's meorizing features